# How do I add an image to a sql database

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, forms

I am trying to insert a title, description and an image into an sql database, below is the form.
However, the code breaks after the form is submitted. I get redirected to the next page but none of the code in the next file gets processed.

It worked fine before I added the function to add an image and there was just text.

here is the code for the form that does not get processed correctly:

```
<?php
if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    echo "<form action='/origo/addnewtopic.php?cid=".$_GET['cid']."&scid=".$_GET['scid']."'
          method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
          <p>Titel: </p>
          <input type='text' id='topic' name='topic' size='100' />
          <p>Innehåll: </p>
          <textarea id='content' name='content'></textarea><br />
          <input type='file' name='image'>
          <input type='submit' value='Lägg till' name='submit'/></form>"; ?>
```

And if anyone wonders, this is the file that it sends the info to that is trying to insert text and image to the database, but none of this gets processed.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include ('dbconn.php');

        $topic = addslashes($_POST['topic']);
        $content = nl2br(addslashes($_POST['content']));
        
        $image = ($_FILES['image']);
        
        $cid = $_GET['cid'];
        $scid = $_GET['scid'];

        $insert = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO topics (`category_id`, `subcategory_id`, `author`, `title`, `content`, `date_posted`)
                                      VALUES ('".$cid."', '".$scid."', '".$_SESSION['username']."', '".$topic."', '".$content."', NOW());");
                                      
        $tid = mysql_insert_id();
        die($tid);
        
        if($image) {
        $insert2 = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO images (`category_id`, `subcategory_id`, `topic_id`, `image`)
                                      VALUES ('".$cid."', '".$scid."', '".$tid."', '".$image."');
                                      }
        else {
            die("no image");
        }

        if ($insert) {
            header("Location: /origo/topics.php?cid=".$cid."&scid=".$scid."");
        } else {
        die("error");
      }
?>
```

Comment: See about sql injection and the importanve of prepared and bound queries.

Comment: Store Image path rather then Storing Image into DB.

Answer (score 0):

try using blob datatype in the DB.
also here

```
$content = nl2br(addslashes($_POST['content']));
```

You must use $_FILES rather than $_POST. As the files like images are being stored in an array $_FILES that is later being extracted from. Also you must use file_get_contents for :

```
$content = nl2br(addslashes(file_get_contents($_POST['content'])));
```

Hope this helps a little

Comment: Thanks, but i am using $_FILES for $image = ($_FILES['image']); but $content is only handling text, so it should not need that, right? Also, i think the problem has to be somewhere in the form as the code for putting stuff in sql is not even getting processed.

Comment: What is `addslashes` for?

Answer (score -1):

I have tried to insert image from database using `php PDO`. i have not save image directly i have store image path in my database. i am store in image path in my database.

```
<?php

//This is a database connection
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=newdb;", 'root', '');

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <!-- This is a post type form it is a upload images -->
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="img" required /><br><br>
        <button type="submit" name="submit-img">Store Image</button>
    </form>
</body>
<html/>
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit-img']))
{
    $type = ['image/jpg', 'image/png', 'image/jpeg'];  //Image type name
    
    $img = $_FILES['img']; //Fetch files 

    if (in_array($img['type'], $type)) //Check file type is image or not
    {       
        $file_tmp_name = $_FILES['img']['tmp_name']; 
        $file_name = $_FILES['img']['name'];
        $folder = "images/".$file_name; 
        echo $folder;
        if (move_uploaded_file($file_tmp_name, $folder)) //Upload image in folder
        {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO images (img) VALUES (?)";
            $insert_img = $conn->prepare($sql);
            
            if ($insert_img->execute([$file_name])) //This is a image path store in database
            {
                echo "<script>alert('image upload successfully...')</script>";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "Image cannot uploaded please try again";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo "file cannot uploaded";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<br>Please upload an image";
    }           
}
?>
```